# Is there any decomposition theorem for permutation groups?

Tags: group-theory

I know that there is decomposition theorem for finite abelian groups. Is there any known theorem for decomposition of permutation groups? Here decomposition means any permutation group can be written as a direct product of smaller groups.

Comment: Decomposition how?

Comment: @ Randall 1 question edited for more detail.

Comment: Since every group is isomorphic to a permutation group by Cayley's Theorem, you are asking whether all groups can be decomposed as direct products, which is clearly false. (The definition of a permutation group that I am familiar with is a subgroup of a symmetric group.)

Comment: I think the answer is "no" because if $n\geq 5$ then $S_n$ always has a simple group of index $2$, which is $A_n$. No decomposition can "avoid" this subgroup, because of the index, so you must split as $A_n\times C_2$, where $C_2$ is cyclic of order two. This does not happen (why?). [I (incorrectly) interpreted the question as "can $S_n$ be decomposed" rather than "can every subgroup of $S_n$ be decomposed".]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is no, at least for $n \geq 5$.

Suppose there was such a decomposition $S_n = H \times K$ with neither $H$ or $K$ trivial. It then follows that $H$ and $K$ are isomorphic to normal subgroups of $S_n$ because they are kernels of the homomorphisms $H \times K \to K$ and $H \times K \to H$.

They cannot be isomorphic groups $H=K$ as that would imply $|S_n|=|H|^2$, yet the largest prime $p$ less than $n$ always divides $n!$ only once.

Finally, the non-trivial normal subgroups of $S_n$ are well known. For $n \geq 5$, there is only one non-trivial normal subgroup of $S_n$ and that is $A_n$. [See Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group#Normal_subgroups). Hence two normal subgroups is impossible.